# Как уменьшить время выполнения MySQL запроса?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, select, settimeout

Уважаемые форумчане!

У меня есть sql-запрос к базе, в которой в таблице "users" 100 000 строк, а в таблице "friends" 20 000 000 записей. Я пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос в phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT `friends`.`friend_age` 
FROM `friends` 
WHERE `id_user` 
IN(SELECT `users`.`uid` FROM `users` WHERE `age`=13 AND `number_of_friends` <> 0) 
AND `friend_age` <> 0 ORDER BY `friend_age`
```

При попытке выполнения запроса, всё зависает.... Потом через какое-то время phpMyAdmin выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\XAMPP\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 290`

Я уже пробовала создавать индексы полей, по которым осуществляется выборка так, как написано здесь:
[MySQL: использование индексов](http://kurepin.ru/php/index/). Однако, это никак не помогло, запрос по-прежнему не выполняется. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Попробовала посмотреть с помощью `EXPLAIN`, что не так и поняла, что первый индекс не очень хороший:
[image: Результат Работы операции EXPLAIN]

Однако, как прооптимизировать пока не ясно. Заходила сюда:
[5.2.1. Синтаксис оператора EXPLAIN (получение информации о SELECT)](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/explain.html)

Пока что тоже не особо помогло((( Хоть кто-нибудь, отзовитесь пожалуйста! Оч нужна помощь!!!

**P.S.**: добавила индекс по столбцу `id_user` в таблице `friends` и первый индекс стал лучше:

[image: Улучшение индексов]

Comment: Нужно смигрировать с меты на основной сайт.

Comment: @VladD, я вас не понимаю. Я зашла под своей учёткой как обычно и задала вопрос. До этого система говорила, что всё впорядке, что мои аккаунты объединены. ЧТО ещё нужно?

Comment: Ну, вы задали вопрос на Мете, а надо было на основном сайте. Подождите немного, я думаю, его перенесут.

Comment: @VladD, а вы можете мне помочь?)))))

Comment: Вряд ли, у меня нет прав модератора. (И я не очень разбираюсь в SQL.)

Comment: Возможно, ваша база данных не умеет оптимизировать subquery, и вам надо попробовать переписать на JOIN.

Comment: @VladD, мой вопросик переехал))) больше не буду плутать)
Немного непонятно как применять join, насколько я понимаю, это объединение результатов двух запросов, а мне нужно данные из одного запроса применить как критерий поиска в другом запросе.

Comment: Возможно, что-то такое подойдёт: `select friend_age from friend join users on id_user = uid where age = 13`? Но тут наверняка нужен ещё distinct где-то.

Comment: Решение проблемы, затронутой в этом вопросе, находится здесь: [Как быстро вычислить медиану запросом mySql?][1]

  [1]: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420809/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-mysql/420810#420810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select distinct f.friend_age
from fiends f
  join users u on f.user_id = u.uid
where 
  u.age = 13
  and f.friend_age<>0
order by f.friend_age
```

Индекс для `users` по `age` (он у вас есть судя по всему).
Индекс для `friends` по `user_id`.

Если будет виснуть, explain этого запроса покажите, возможно придется хинтами пользоваться.

Ограничение на количество друзей не нужно, т.к. выберутся только те, у кого они есть.

**UPD**

К сожалению, проблему, описанную в вопросе, решить не удастся. Вопрос тут не в индексах (хотя без них будет все еще хуже), а в объеме данных.

Для получения медианы достаточно результата такого запроса:

```
select f.friend_age, count(*) cnt
from fiends f
  join users u on f.user_id = u.uid
where 
  u.age = 13
  and f.friend_age<>0
group by f.friend_age
```

Таким образом получаете агрегированный список возрастов (мы выяснили, что аналогичный запрос с distinct'ом выполняется за более-менее разумное время).

Дальше рассчитать медиану уже будет не так сложно. Если сложности все-таки возникнут, лучше оформить другой вопрос.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное за ответ!))) Только я не совсем понимаю, что значит f и u. Это какие-то псевдонимы в mySql?

Comment: обычно их называют "алиасы"

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, запрос отработал, даже уложился в тайм-аут 300 с. Но мне как раз нужно чтобы не уникальные возраста были, а все. Поэтому слово "DISTINCT" лишнее. Попробовала без него, запрос завис...

Comment: @cat_woman уточните, пожалуйста, для какой цели вам нужны миллионы одинаковых чисел в пределах возрастов друзей тринадцатилетних? Запрос завис по той причине, что вернется слишком много записей. Сформулируйте какую задачу вы решаете, может быть найдется более простое и соответственно быстрое решение?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я пытаюсь вычислить медиану возрастов друзей. Для этого получаю выборку из всех возрастов друзей 13-летних пользователей.

Comment: @cat_woman `select avg(f.friend_age)...` не решит вашу задачу? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, среднее и медиана - это же разные вещи. Мне нужна именно медиана.

Comment: @cat_woman обновил ответ.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо ещё раз!))) Да, с вычислением медианы нет никаких проблем. Проблема была именно в скорости работы. Ну, видимо придётся смириться, что для 100 возрастов прога будет работать несколько часов.....

Comment: @cat_woman даже если вам надо посчитать медиану для каждого возможного адреса, даже если это делать в цикле по каждому возрасту, прога будет работать не больше нескольких десятков секунд. Я сгенерил у себя 100к пользователей и 1кк друзей для них с рандомными значениями возраста. Выгрузка запроса в ответе во временную таблицу заняла 0,058 секунды, обработка и нахождение медианы по полученному списку заняло 0,007 секунды. Ваш случай должен отличаться максимум на порядок, но не на три-пять-десять... Задайте вопрос по медиане, там не так все прозрачно, но гонять миллионы записей в циклах не нужно.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23419/discussion-between-cat-woman-and-yura-ivanov).