# Как быстро вычислить медиану запросом mySql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, select, request

Есть таблица friends, в которой 20 000 000 записей и есть таблица users, в которой 100 000. В таблице users хранится информация о возрасте пользователей и количестве друзей. В таблице friends содержится информация об id друзей для всех пользователей и возраста друзей. Требуется найти медиану возрастов друзей для пользователей определённой возрастной группы, например 13, 14, 15 и т.д.

Данный вопрос - продолжение обсуждения этого вопроса: [Как уменьшить время выполнения MySQL запроса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420619/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/420672#420672)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вычисление медианы можно реализовать одним запросом (в сети есть примеры) соединением списка друзей самого с собой, находя середину интервала. Это подходит для случая когда практически все значения различны и их не так много. Однако в данном случае в этом нет необходимости, достаточно получить количество друзей соответствующих возрастов и работать с агрегированными данными.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ages 
select f.age, count(*) cnt 
from friends f 
  join users u on f.user_id = u.id 
where 
  u.age = 13 
  and f.age<>0 
group by f.age; 

SET @total := 0; 
select @total:=sum(cnt) from temp_ages; 
SET @cnt:=0; 

SELECT age FROM ( 
SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+cnt aggcnt, age, cnt 
FROM temp_ages 
ORDER BY age 
) ta 
WHERE aggcnt>=@total/2 
LIMIT 1;
```

Результат получения возрастов друзей с количествами кладем во временную таблицу. Записей в этой таблице будет, очевидно, немного - не больше ста. Затем воспользовавшись данными по количествам получаем общее количество (`@total`) друзей с со всеми возрастами уже из временной таблицы. И получаем медиану, выполняя итерацию по сортированному списку возрастов пока не дойдем до середины.

Следует отметить, что возможны случаи попадания на границы интервалов, когда медиана будет не из значений возрастов, для этого необходимо дополнительно проанализировать `@total` (на четность) и результат, который будет в `@cnt` по итогам выполнения последнего запроса.

Comment: благодарю вас за исчерпывающий ответ!))) Запросы летают моментально!