# Выборка строк с последней датой

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы:

1) Главная `id, name`

2) Таблица с датой, где pid = id в главной таблице.

```
id, pid, date, value
```

3) Таблица с датой в формате int, где `pid` = `id` в главной таблице. (yy-год, mm-месяц)

```
id, pid, yy, mm, value
```

В один запрос нужно посчитать кол-во строк, с записями из этих таблиц для последних дат. Пробую два подхода:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    mainTable c
    LEFT JOIN subTable1 s1 ON c.id = s1.pid AND s.date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM subTable1 WHERE pid = c.id) 
    LEFT JOIN subTable2 s2 ON c.id = s2.pid AND ((s2.yy*100) + s2.mm) IN (SELECT MAX(yy)*10 + MAX(mm) FROM subTable2 WHERE pid=c.id)
```

Способ понятный, компактный, но очень долгий, на 40000 строк делается 60 секунд.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.id AS id,
        MAX(s1.date) AS date1,
        MAX(s2.yy*100 + s2.mm) AS date2
    FROM
        mainTable c
        LEFT JOIN subTable1 s1 ON c.id = s1.pid
        LEFT JOIN subTable2 s2 ON c.id = s2.pid
    GROUP BY c.id
    ) tt
    LEFT JOIN LEFT JOIN subTable1 s1 ON tt.id = s1.cid AND s1.date IN (tt.date1)
    LEFT JOIN subTable2 s2 ON tt.id = s2.cid AND s2.yy*100 + s2.mm IN (tt.date2)
```

Способ не очень удобный, т.к. запрос получается гораздо длиннее, но зато на 40000 строк выполняется в 4 раза быстрее.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такая разница? Можно ли как-то подправить 1й запрос, чтобы устранить её? Может есть какой-нибудь иной способ, чтобы получить нужную мне информацию?

P.S. На самом деле таблиц гораздо больше, запросы всё время дополняются, всё постарался упростить, чтобы облегчить понимание задачи.

UPD: важен именно принцип получения данных в запросе, когда они нужны для последующего использования в этом запросе. Т.е. куда поместить вложенный запрос и почему во втором варианте получается на много быстрее.

Comment: 1) было бы не плохо увидеть `show create table` для таблиц (больше индексы интересуют) 2) было бы не плохо увидеть `explain select...` + профилирование запросов 3) первую таблицу можно смело выбросить из запросов, она вам не нужна (для текущих запросов, в исходном запросе, возможно, без нее никак) 4) а разница между 2 и 3 таблицей какая? Может можно выбросить одну таблицу не потеряв смысл всего запроса? 5) а есть возможность изменить структуру БД? Вместо `yy` и `mm` может лучше было бы одно поле с началом месяца хранить? Если эти поля нужны, то поле с датой можно и просто так хранить

Comment: Вам правильно **ВОРОН** говорит. **explain select** было бы неплохо увидеть, чтобы оценить какие поля и как у вас проиндексированы. Вот ссылка на вопрос, где похожая ситуация обсуждается, может он будет вам чем-то полезен: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420619/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: А зачем третья таблица? Вам надо подсчитать количество записей в главной таблице у последних дат?

Comment: "первую таблицу можно смело выбросить из запросов, она вам не нужна" - нужна, там ещё 20 LEFT JOIN с разными таблицами, которые именно на ней завязаны. а разница между 2 и 3 таблицей какая? "Может можно выбросить одну таблицу не потеряв смысл всего запроса?" - нельзя, там нужные(разные) данные. "а есть возможность изменить структуру БД? Вместо yy и mm может лучше было бы одно поле с началом месяца хранить?" - никак, это таблица биллинга, я могу только считывать записи от туда.

Comment: Важен сам принцип использования данных при LEFT JOIN, которые нужно получить в этом же запросе

Comment: 1 PRIMARY c index  del 1  31499 Using index
1 PRIMARY cs ref cid cid 4 bgbilling.c.id 10 
1 PRIMARY cb ref PRIMARY,cid cid 4 bgbilling.c.id 10 Using index
3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY contract_balance ref PRIMARY,cid cid 4 bgbilling.c.id 10 Using index
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY contract_status ref cid cid 4 bgbilling.c.id 10 Using where - explain select, bgbilling.contract_status - это subTable1, bgbilling.contract_balance - subTable2, подскажите, как отформатировать.

Comment: "Вот ссылка на вопрос, где похожая ситуация обсуждается, может он будет вам чем-то полезен: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420619/" - там человек просто использует вложенный запрос, где он не нужен, как я понимаю, у меня же без него никак не обойтись...

Comment: "А зачем третья таблица? Вам надо подсчитать количество записей в главной таблице у последних дат?" - Таблиц на самом деле много больше, в java коде к ним подставляются разные WHERE, чтобы в зависимости от нужно пользователя получать результаты. Т.е. далее может следовать како-нибудь условие к любой из таблиц для получения нужной выборки.

Comment: @STepeR Результат `EXPLAIN` добавьте в вопрос. Оформить его можно в виде кода. Желательно вставить с заголовками таблицы (id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys...)

Comment: @STepeR И послушайте BOPOH'а по каждому пункту

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что в первом запросе проблема во втором `LEFT JOIN`. Последнее условие не может использовать индексы в принципе, а при сложных запросах - это долгое время

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, с индексами вы разобрались. Теперь пойдем от SQL. Первый запрос выполняется долго, потому как вы берёте все записи из таблицы *mainTable*, а потом джойните отфильтрованные данные из двух других таблиц. Во втором случае вы сначала делаете фильтр, а потом выбираете данные, соответствующие этому фильтру. Полагаю, разница в скорости связана с этим.

Смотрим на код. У вас **Left Join**, а значит выбираются все записи из *mainTable* (даже те, которым нет соответствия в таблицах *subTable1* и *subTable2*). С этими данными связываются данные из двух других таблиц, при этом записи из *mainTable* может потенциально соответствовать по несколько записей в таблице *subTable1* и *subTable2*. (Допускаю, что возможны связи один-к-одному, но исходя из приведенного SQL этого не видно.) А это значит, что выборке данные из *mainTable* могут быть посчитаны несколько раз (см. [упрощенный пример, где данные умножены](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5439f/1/0)).

Важно, кстати, отметить еще один момент: возможна ситуации, когда запись с некоторым **pid** есть в таблице *subTable1*, но нет записи с этим же **pid** в таблице *subTable2*. А значит, не ясно, что именно считать: все записи в таблице *mainTable*, которым есть соответствия в обеих зависимых таблицах (за определенный период), или же те, которым есть соответствие хотя бы в одной из таблиц?

*Интресный момент. Если выбрать только уникальные записи (небольшая модификация первого запроса из вопроса), то вы получите количество записей в таблице mainTable:*

```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINT c.id)
     FROM mainTable c
LEFT JOIN subTable1 s1 ON c.id = s1.pid AND s.date IN (SELECT MAX(date) 
                                                         FROM subTable1 
                                                        WHERE pid = c.id) 
LEFT JOIN subTable2 s2 ON c.id = s2.pid AND ((s2.yy*100) + s2.mm) IN (SELECT MAX(yy)*10 + MAX(mm) 
                                                                        FROM subTable2 
                                                                       WHERE pid = c.id)
```

эквивалентно:

```
   SELECT count(*)
     FROM mainTable
```

В *subTable1* пишется нормальная дата, в *subTable2* пишутся год и месяц. Соответственно, фильтр по дате в *subTable1* позволяет нам отфильтровать данные сильнее, чем фильтр по дате в *subTable2*. При этом возможны два сценария:

- данные пишутся в таблицы *subTable1* и *subTable2* одновременно (допустим, там хранятся бинарные данные или большие тексты),
- данные пишутся сначала в одну таблицу, потом - в другую и разница во времени может составлять минуты, часы или дни.

Первый сценарий сильно облегчает запросы на выборку (достаточно одного фильтра). Второй создает проблемы, которые требуется учесть. Например, запись в *subTable1* сделана 31 декабря 2015 года, а соответствующая запись в *subTable2* - 1 января 2016. Приведенные в вопросе SQL-запросы такие пары проигнорируют если в таблице *subTable1* появилась запись за 1 января.

**Пробуем построить запрос**

Если связь между главной и зависимыми таблицами **"один-к-одному" (как обязательная, так и обязательная на одном конце)**, то таблица *mainTable* в запросе не нужна. Во вложенном запросе выбираем максимальные даты, джойним по этим датам данные из таблицы *subTable1*. По ID из главной таблицы выбираем данные из *subTable2*. Фильтруем по максимальной дате данные из *subTable2*:

```
   SELECT count(*)
     FROM (SELECT MAX(s1.date) max_date1,
                  MAX(s2.yy)*100 + MAX(s2.mm) max_date2
             FROM subTable1 s1
             JOIN subTable2 s2) h
LEFT JOIN subTable1 s1 ON s1.date = h.max_date1
LEFT JOIN subTable2 s2 ON s1.pid = s2.pid
    WHERE (s2.yy*100) + s2.mm = h.max_date2;
```

Если данные в таблицы *subTable1* и *subTable2* пишутся в один и тот же день, то запрос можно упростить:

```
   SELECT count(*)
     FROM (SELECT MAX(s1.date) max_date1
             FROM subTable1 s1) h
LEFT JOIN subTable1 s1 ON s1.date = h.max_date1
LEFT JOIN subTable2 s2 ON s1.pid = s2.pid;
```

Важно учесть, что запрос не считает записи из *mainTable*, которым ничего не соответствует в таблицах *subTable1* и *subTable2* (если связь "один-к-одному" обязательная на одном конце). Я бы рекомендовал такие записи считать отдельно, а потом суммировать результаты.

Тип связи "многие-ко-многим" между главной и зависимыми таблицами вызывает вопросы, ключевые из которых: что именно нужно посчитать (*см. второй абзац в самом начале*) и какая логика заложена в БД (*см. третий абзац*)?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял у Вас есть

```
main: id, name
date: id, main_id, date, value
strange_date: id, main_id, mm, yy, value
```

и Вам надо найти количество записей с максимальной датой в date и strange_date в разрезе main_id?

Я бы пошёл от противного:

```
    select main_id, cnt from (
      select main_id, date, count(*) as cnt from (
          select main_id, date 
          from date 
          union
          select main_id, str_to_date(concat(yy,'-',mm,'-01')) as date 
          from strange_date 
     )
     group by main_id, date
   ) as a 
   group by main_id, cnt 
   having date = (
     select max(date) from (
       select main_id, date 
       from date 
       union
       select main_id, str_to_date(concat(yy,'-',mm,'-01')) as date 
       from strange_date 
     ) as b
    where b.main_id = a.id
   )
```

И сделал бы наверное ещё вьюхи на юнион для того чтобы запрос был красивый типа - all_date_records - чтобы не тащить разную логику работы с представлением даты.

Comment: union и having не вариант, ибо там очень много сторонних таблиц... Есть ещё аналогичный запрос с получением именно значений всяких, который связан с этим, его не привожу, ибо важен сам принцип получения данных, которые нужны в этом же запросе. Подход с LEFT JOIN и короче и по быстродействию должен выигрывать(могу здесь ошибаться, если так, то поправьте меня)

Comment: А Вам действительно надо расширять проект посредством кодерства sql запросов? Может имеет смысл создать объектную модель, которая будет отвечать прикладной логике, и всю внутрянку с оптимизацией sql'я вынести под капот, и параллельно там уже оптимизировать как угодно?

Comment: Может вы и правы, но: 1) Я не имею в этом опыта, что в принципе не страшно 2) Я не могу принять такое решение, ибо сказали делать так, т.к. так всё сделано и так будет делаться... Запросы по 150 строк - это конечно страшно, но ничего не поделаешь (

Comment: Запросы о 150 строк это не страшно, когда это автоген, а не ручная сборка