# Группировка по полю: как получить максимальное значение в пределах группы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `comments`:

```
id | cid | time | text
-------------------------
1  | 9   | 1000 | текст
2  | 9   | 1001 | текст2
3  | 10  | 1000 | текст3
4  | 10  | 1003 | текст4
5  | 11  | 1088 | текст5
```

В результате нужно получить только поля `text` и `cid` по `MAX(time)` для каждого `cid` (id: 2, 4, 5)

Пример результата:

```
    cid | text
    ------------
    9   | текст2
    10  | текст4
    11  | текст5
```

Как составить соответствующий SELECT-запрос?

Comment: было уже где-то

Comment: уже решил проблему так: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY time DESC) as tbl GROUP BY  tbl.cid

Comment: Что делать, если таблица содержит несколько значений `MAX(time)` для одного и того же `cid`?

Comment: вообще не оптимально, у вас сколько сейчас записей? сделайте там пару десятков миллионов - уже будут проблемы

Comment: Если сможете понять что делается в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465571/5079), то сможете написать нормальный запрос. Но где-то был другой вопрос (который больше подходит к вашему, чем первый), где это было нормально расписано

Answer (score 1):

1. ответ с вложенным запросом ошибочный, он будет не всегда правильно работать.
2. конечное решение зависит от того, может ли таблица содержать несколько одинаковых max(time) для одного cid и нужны ли все или только какое-то одно.
3. Есть, как минимум, 5 способов решения вашей задачи, описанных в статье [Группировка в MySQL](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Ответ из комментариев от автора [ultrabatya](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179410/ultrabatya)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT
     *
   FROM
     comments
   ORDER BY
     time DESC) as tbl
GROUP BY
  tbl.cid
```